# checking input command in dos batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am running input arguments as a command in my dos batch file as I asked in:
[Run an input parameter as command in dos batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396311/run-a-input-parameter-as-command-in-dos-batch-script).
That works, however the problem I am having: checking if the input command if it's empty.
What I do:

```
SETLOCAL
set CMD=%*
echo Running command [%CMD%]
IF "%CMD%"=="" (
 echo "Input argument missing: command"
 GOTO :end
)
echo "XXX %CMD%"
```

And running:

```
script.bat echo "a b c"
```

Will output:

```
Running command [echo "a b c"]
b was unexpected at this time.
```

This occurs in the IF condition, but why?

How can I check if my input is empty. I know how to check if a string is empty in dos, but for some reason it doesn't work in this combination :(
BTW: If I remove the IF condition it works well, that is: the command is executed correctly.

- Ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test for the absence of parameters first, then assign and process the command:

```
IF .%1 == . (
 echo "Input argument missing: command"
 GOTO :eof
)

SETLOCAL    
set CMD=%*
echo Running command [%CMD%]
echo "XXX %CMD%"
```

As to the "Why?", it's because the quotation mark in the value of `CMD` (the one before `a`) closes the quotation mark before `%CMD%`, and so the string appears as `"echo "a b c""`, and thus `b` becomes separated from the string, which causes the command processor to fail. (It expects a comparison token, like `==` or `EQU`, but not some strange `b`).

Comment: +1, as you are always correct. But I prefere `if "%~1"==""` as it's mostly safer

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to difficult :(

Comment: @jeb: Thanks. I thought about `"%~1"==""` too, but then it could be misleading if for some reason the first parameter was simply `""` (and the second one was a non-empty value). I mean, we can't be sure if it's all right to specify `""` or not, so I thought I'd go with the `.%1==.` test.

Comment: Yes, then an empty `""` fails, but strings like `&` or `<` doesn't create syntax errors, but the only realy safe version seems to be the [_REM technic_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5338799/463115)